# Comparing numpy array having repetitions with list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Following the previous question as follows
[Comparing list elements with a column in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695583/comparing-list-elements-with-a-column-in-numpy-array/56695632#56695632), I have implemented the following code to compare the list elements with array.

```
list=['M', 'R', 'W']
array=[['M',360.0, 360.0],['R', 135.9, 360.0],['W', 101.4, -125.4], ['Y', 115.8, -160.4],['Y', 115.8, -160.4],['W', 101.4, -125.4]]

new_array = [x for x in array if x[0] in list]
print(new_array)
```

The output is as below.

```
new_array=[['M', 360.0, 360.0], ['R', 135.9, 360.0], ['W', 101.4, -125.4], ['W', 101.4, -125.4]]
```

Here we see that `"W"`is repeated twice.

How can I take the only the top matching elements in the list and ignore the others if it is present in list.

**So the output should be like as follows.**

```
new_array=[['M', 360.0, 360.0], ['R', 135.9, 360.0], ['W', 101.4, -125.4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using the `index` which will return the 1st match

```
l1=[x[0] for x in array]
[array[y] for y in [l1.index(x) for x in l]]
[['M', 360.0, 360.0], ['R', 135.9, 360.0], ['W', 101.4, -125.4]]
```